# Xcode: create new custom templates and code snippets?

Tags: macos, perl, xcode, templates

I'm trying to tame Xcode for writing things in Perl. Naturally, I'd like to use the "IDE features", not just the text editor. That includes Perl-specific templates, which brings me to the question:

Is there a decent way of creating custom templates and template groups in Xcode 5?

I didn't find anything in the documentation. Strange.
Please, do not suggest using Padre or some other IDE / text editor. My question is about Xcode.

Comment: Same question was already answered on Stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491826/how-to-create-project-templates-in-xcode-4. Accepted answer to the linked question contains detailed guide on creating custom templates and template groups.

Comment: This Stack Overflow question and answer may be of interest to you if you would like to tame Xcode for Perl development: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24092254/705157 ("Can I use Xcode as an IDE for Perl scripts?").